# How do I tweak the settings of Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070?

Tags: wifi, drivers, wifi-hotspot

I don't know how to tweak the setting of this interface:

```
PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

phy1    wlan1           rt2800usb       Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070
```

Unlike Windows, It doesn't accept to create hotspot:

```bsh
┌──(rootmmt)-[/home/mohammedmehditber]
└─# create_ap wlan1 wlan1 MyAccessPoint my_password
ERROR: Your adapter can not be a station (i.e. be connected) and an AP at the same time
```

Here are the capabilities:

```bsh
Valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8,
                   total <= 8, #channels <= 1
```

Comment: The capabilities are available in the output of `iw phy1 info`  at the entries under `valid interface combinations:`. you should add them to the question.

Comment: I've done that and edited the post @A.B

Comment: Indeed I'm not sure this device, with the current Linux driver, can be used at the same time as STA and AP on Linux. Because there's no entry like `#{ managed } <= X` under valid interface combinations, meaning it can't be combined as STA (but multiple AP could be created though).

Comment: Maybe It is because of the actual particular driver, but the hotspot works in Windows 11, yet It disables itself randomly sometimes maybe because of a bug in Windows 11

Comment: Is there a tool that alter the settings of Wi-Fi interfaces like Windows's driver proprieties?

Comment: It's all documented there:  https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw#adding_interfaces_with_iw  but the limitation is not about the tool, it's about *the driver for this card*. create_ap already detects there's such limitation as returned by the iw command (valid interface combinations...)